# How can I pass data between forms?

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I have this form below:

[image: frmMembers]

As soon as I press the button "New Payment" I want the form to take the values inside the member ID text box, the first name text box and the last name text box and automatically load them to the fields respectively on the form below:

[image: frmPayments]

I'm thinking of doing it with global variables but I've never worked with VBA. Can someone explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Global variables would be one way. Properly abstracting the data into a *model* class that can be passed around between instances of forms would be another. I'd argue that global variables is plain ugly and wrong and wouldn't even be considered an option in any other programming language (no idea why it's suddenly acceptable in VBA code), but your mileage may vary.

Comment: It also seems to me that you are writing more code than necessary because you are using 2 popup forms to do the work. If you put the payment form as a subform, you get the functionality you're after for free and with less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several noted, if you use a tab control, you can put that form as a sub-form, and then in most cases no code at all will be required.

However, there are quite a few ways to pass values.

The cleanest code, and no global variables?

I suggest this approach:

You don’t pass the values, but “grab” the previous form object.

So, in your 2nd forms code module, you declare a variable called frmPrevious. This var is declared at the forms module level.

So, you code module will look like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public frmPrevious     As Form
```

Now, in the forms on-open event, you do this:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

   Set frmPrevious = Screen.ActiveForm

End Sub
```

Note that your current form does NOT become the active form until the open event is completed. In fact, you can even put the above code in the forms on-load event.

Ok, now.

Your new payment button code?

With the above, you are free to grab “any” values you want from the previous form.

Eg:

```
Me.CompanyName = frmPrevious!CompanyName
Me.member_id   = fromPrevous!ID
```

Etc.

So, the above is nice, since then you can pass/use and reference ANY value or control from the previous form.

However, you should not be re-copy the LastName box, but in fact ONLY set the customer_ID or some such to the customer, and then you can in the future reference/gget phone number, city etc.

Re-copy of a value is  very very BAD approach, as you are breaking the relational design, and you wind up writing tons and tons of more code then is required.

IN fact, in your code, likely the new payment button has to go to a NEW record FIRST, else the above code will start to overwrite existing values.

And, if the user hits new payment, and THEN decides to bail out and not add? Well, then you going to wind up with blank records.

What this really means is you should put the code that “copies” and “sets” the values from the previous form in the before insert event. This event ONLY will fire for new records, so you don’t need special code to check or worry if you going to accident over-write values in a known good record.